# multi select option printing

Tags: php

I am just a beginner in php. 
I am trying to print the values of the form when submitted. I used the following code for hobbies which is a field of my form.

```
<?php
    $hobbies=array("Reading books","Listening to music","Swimming","Watching TV");

foreach($hobbies as $key=>$value) {
    $hobbyvalues='<input name="hobbies" type="checkbox" value="'.$value.'" />'.$value."</br>";
    echo $hobbyvalues;
}
?>
```

I store the selected hobbies like the following.

```
$hobbies = $_POST["hobbies"];
echo $hobbies;
```

I checked it by selecting more than one hobby and submit the form. But my result prints only the last selected hobby.

I need my code to display all the selected hobbies. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

make it like this

```
<input name="hobbies[]"
```

Comment: ...or name="hobbies[$value]"?

Comment: If i am using this the result just showed array not my selected values.